# How to make APIs on server secured (HTTPS) with cloudflare

Tags: ssl, https, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I just secured my domain with CloudFlare’s  SSL certificate. And it works well!

I still have a problem though, I have an express server that I'm using serving APIs on `myIpAddress:2053/api/request` and the certificate I generated doesn’t work well for it.

It still gives me that the API is not secure and I have to go with (Advanced => Proceed to ------- (unsafe)) on Google Chrome and other browsers.

Here’s a peak on my code.

```js
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/private/key.pem", “utf8”); //CF’s SSL key
const certificate = fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem", “utf8”); //CF’s SSL cert
let credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(HTTPS started on port ${PORT});
});
```

My APIs have to be secure too in order to communicate with the Frontend. It should be similar to that : `**https**://myIpAddress:2053/api/request`

My server is on DigitalOcean, using Ubuntu as a OS, and NGINX.

Comment: Do not use IP addresses in HTTPS URL. While you technically can have X.509 certificates covering IP addresses, in the standard case a certificate will cover hostnames, not IP addresses and hence will never match for HTTPS URLs using IP addresses.

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When browsers do ssl handshake with server, browsers will check domain matching with Subject CN in ssl certificate.

This is command to view your certificate:

> openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -in ssl.crt

[image]